# Work done in bringing down a body

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, work

A block of mass $30$ kg is being brought down by a chain. If the block acquires a speed of 40.0 cm/s in dropping down $2.00$ m, find the work done by the chain during the process.

I have calculated this. The acceleration of the block if the frame of reference is attached to the block, is $a-g=-9.76 $
So the work done comes out to be $-586$ J.

What is the significance *-ve* sign here? And will the work done be *+ve*?

Also, the work done is also equal to the change in kinetic energy. Change in kinetic energy = $2.4$ J. This does not match the answer. Where am I wrong?

Comment: You've made an assumption about the motion of the block that is not justified.  Picture in your head what you imagine the motion to be.  Read the problem carefully.  What have you taken as an assumption, but is not mentioned at all in the question?

Comment: @AnubhavGoel What you wrote is not quite correct.  Also, *do not provide answers to homework problems*.

Comment: Work done is energy transferred. Since the block is gaining all of its energy from gravity (I assume), then the chain is doing no work on the block, since no energy is being transferred. The earth is doing work on the block, not the chain.

Comment: @AnthonyHolmes The block is being lowered by the chain.  It is certainly doing work on the block.

Comment: Actually, upon further reflection, there is not enough information in this problem to arrive at a definitive solution.  You made an assumption, but when I looked at it I made a *different* assumption concerning the missing information.  Your assumption is just as valid as mine, so my initial comment above is off the mark.   Consider *carefully* your last paragraph.  The solution to your problem lies in correctly interpreting what you wrote there.  (What you wrote there is correct, BTW.)

Comment: OK because it is not mentioned in the question that what is the initial velocity of the block, I can't assume it to be zero. So it is quite insignificant to work out this question by finding out the change in kinetic energy. But then, how can the acceleration and work done be calculated?

Comment: But how can you take 'a' as 0.4 m/s^2 and remember you have just velocity being given.

Comment: Now *I'm* guilty of mis-reading.  Your second paragraph is garbled.  The acceleration of the block in its own frame of reference is zero.  How did you calculate $a$?  And I think that the only way to solve this is to assume that the initial speed is zero.

Comment: Work done by chain is change in kinetic energy. Final energy should be 591.6J. But it is $1/2mv^2$ = 2.4J. So, work done by chain is 591.6-2.4 = 589.2J.

Comment: @AnubhavGoel NO!  Word done by chain is *not* the change in KE.  I give up on this problem.  It's too poorly worded.

Comment: Work done by chain is change in energy of chain. Final energy should be mgh = 588J. But it is $1/2mv^2$ = 2.4J. So, work done by chain is 588-2.4 = 585.6J. This my last attempt now. Good Night

Comment: @AnubhavGoel Your heart is in the right place, but you are not saying it correctly.   There are two forces on the block: the chain and gravity.   *Both* do work on the block.   But you assume two things:  40 cm/s is the final velocity, and that the initial velocity is zero, neither of which is clear from the statement of the problem!!   The problem as written is broken.   Sleep well, good night.

Answer (score 0):

**What is the significance −ve sign here? And will the work done be +ve?**

If I want to lift some mass upwards I need to apply a force at least equal to it's weight. This means if I want to pull the mass upwards, with a certain acceleration then an additional force has to be supplied along with it's weight. But the resultant force will be the difference in these forces in magnitude. Now, to speak about the direction; w.r.t. (earth whose force acts downwards), the body is moving upwards with a force that can be defined from it's acceleration upwards. Hence the force defined by earth is negative. Now, according to me, it is pulled upward with some force that I exerted. So here the force is positive since the acceleration is in the same sense as the applied force. So the work done by the earth is negative while the work done by me is positive. The magnitudes of both coincide.

The reverse is your case. Now you can think about it.

**Also, the work done is also equal to the change in kinetic energy. Change in kinetic energy =$2.4J$. This does not match the answer.**

According to work energy theorem, if the system is conservative, then the work done on a system will appear as the increase in kinetic energy of the system. But you have applied the wrong velocity in kinetic energy equation. There are something to be added here. The acceleration of the mass is not given. How you calculated that is also not provided. If your answer about the acceleration is right, read the remaining statements. The work done is calculated about a distance of $2m$ with an acceleration of $-9.76m/s^2$. So the velocity is not constant. You have to calculate the change in velocity over that distance. Apply that velocity and you will get the answer, which is the increase in kinetic energy of the mass throughout that distance.
(Hint: The acceleration is uniform over that distance. The final velocity is $40cm/s$. The initial velocity is to be calculate from Torricelli's equation. Find the change in velocity. Apply it in K.E. equation and you will get the answer.)

Comment: How can 'a' is 0.4 m/s^2 when it is given only velocity.

Comment: Acceleration is not $0.4m/s^2$. The velocity given is the final velocity ($0.4m/s$ on reaching $2 m$). From Toricelli's equation, you can calculate the initial velocity. Then find the change in velocity. Apply that velocity in the kinetic energy equation because you are finding change in kinetic energy, not the kinetic energy when the velocity is $0.4m/s$.

Comment: Well it's not clear if  40 cm/s is the *change* in velocity or the *final* velocity.  And how do you find the acceleration?

Comment: It's not the change in velocity. Read the statement one more time. The statement says the ball reached a velocity of $0.4m/s$ on reaching 2m . It is not given the two meters is from the top. So the initial velocity need not be zero. You need to find it using the Toricelli's equation to find initial velocity.  I checked by myself. It will give you the same answer.

Comment: But in the question she has mentioned acceleration ' a' as 0.4 m/s^2, how and even used in the equation a-g.

Comment: @Vaibhav Singh: What you mean? Look the question once again. She has calculated the acceleration as $-9.76m/s^2$

Comment: But look at the eq a- g from where she has calculated. Where g = 9.8m/s^2

Comment: Ok. What's the problem in it. There is acceleration due to gravity downwards and also an acceleration of the mass due to force on the chain. So the resultant acceleration is $a-g$

Comment: @U.K  *Change* vs *final*:  that's *your* interpretation.  *Reality* is that its ambiguous.

Comment: But the value of acceleration is not given as -9.78 in the question so how she can use it in eq a-g.

Comment: @Vaibhav Singh:Actually I have assumed initial velocity to be zero. That's my fault.

Comment: Well now you know your mistake.

Comment: @ Vaibhav Singh: But the question says the mass is going down . But it's not equal to g as it can be seen from the velocity value. The chain exerts some force against the gravity to maintain the descend of the mass. So the resultant acceleration as observed by someone pulling the chain will be $a-g$. The earth measures the acceleration as $g-a$. That things I have mentioned in my answer.

Comment: That's what I'am talking. the initial velocity is not zer. You just apply the Toricelli's equation and find the initial velocity. Calculate the change in velocity. find the change in kinetic energy.  You can see that work done- change in K.E

Comment: So from where have you taken acceleration in your answer as -9.76

Comment: That's calculated by OP, not me.  That acceleration downwards may be provided in the question to OP. But she haven't specified it in the problem. That's a technical defect here. However she may thought that it is not necessary and provided her calculation.

Comment: Now that's the point.

Comment: Your acceleration value $0.4m/s^2$ realy confused me as no such information I can connect with the data in the question. You may have mistyped it. The acceleration is $0.04m/s^2$

Comment: @U.K: Acceleration is not given in the question. I have already mentioned that its my fault to assume the initial velocity to be zero. I've calculated a=0.04m/s² assuming initial velocity to be zero. That's my mistake.

Comment: @ ADITI SAINI. Sorry. my previous comment was on @Vaibhav Singh. I'am sorry that I didn't quote it. I thought that you are provided with the acceleration. But how did you get the acceleration $0.04m/s^2$ assuming the initial velocity $0$?